# where to define allowed telnet port numbers on locahost?

Tags: linux, telnet

I am unable to do telnet on port 8000 while default telnet on port 23 works fine.

What configuration is required?

```
# telnet localhost 8000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused.

# telnet localhost
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
login:
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use telnet? SSH is encrypted, and the preferred method.

Comment: I was just testing node.js connection event on telnet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that nothing is listening on the port 8000.
Try `netstat -apn | grep 8000` to verify is anything listening.

Comment: yes i didn't get any output.

Comment: how to allow telnet on port other than 23?

Comment: To which program are you trying to telnet? That program should be set to use port 8000

Comment: i am doing from the same machine 'localhost', i have a node.js program that is configured to listen on port 8000. do you mean i have to enable listening before telnet ?

Comment: It seems that node.js is not correctly configured to use port 8000.

Comment: oh, yes node.js program has some problem... let me figure out. thanks

Comment: after correcting node.js, i am able to telnet, thanks..